# What is the behavior of error recessive nodes in can protocol

Tags: embedded, communication, can-bus

I found this in can microchip datasheet?"The error passive station waits for six consecutive bits of equal polarity, beginning at the start of the passive error flag. The passive error flag is complete when these 6 equal bits have bee detected" (CAN 2.0 Specification)" So are those consecutive bits dominant or recessive or any ?

Answer (score 0):

"*of equal polarity*" means just that, any.

Six recessive bits complete, and six dominant bits, too.

Answer (score 0):

If a node is "error passive", it means that its error counter has passed the point where it may signal active error frames by pulling the CAN lines to the dominant state and thereby disrupt traffic. Instead it may only pull the lines to the recessive state, meaning that other traffic will take precedence.

So depending on if an error spotted by an error passive node happens during transmission from that node or during reception, the resulting passive error frame of 6 consecutive recessive bits produced by the error passive node may or may not be visible to other nodes.

So the "passive" parts in the quoted text doesn't really make a lot of sense without any such context. 6 consecutive bits of any polarity is simply an error frame. Count enough error frames and you'll go error passive.